# Enviar datos obtenidos de array por mail php

Tags: php, html, smtp

La idea de este envio de mail es recuperar de la base de datos cierta informacion para dar un resumen

Primero obtengo los datos de la base de datos

```
$buscar = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE agencia != '1'";
$acc = $pdo -> prepare($buscar);
$acc -> execute();
```

Seguido de esto comienzo el while junto al codigo html

```
while ($datos = $acc -> fetch()) {
$to="correo@correo.com";
$subject="Para alguien";
$body='codigo html';
//Aqui comienzo hacer condicionales dependiendo del resultado
if ($datos[8] == 'no') {
      $body .= ' <h2>Usuarios que no han hecho nada</h2><br>'.$datos[4].'<br>';
    }
     if ($datos[8] == 'si') {
     $body .= ' <h2>Usuarios que han hecho la apertura</h2><br>'.$datos[4].'<br>';
    }
    if ($datos[8] == 'valijas') {
       $body .= ' <h2>Usuarios que han hecho la valija</h2><br>'.$datos[4].'<br>';
    }
    if ($datos[8] == 'cierre') {
      $body .= ' <h2>Usuarios que han hecho la cierre</h2><br>'.$datos[4].'<br>';
    }
    if ($datos[8] == 'pagoefectivo') {
     $body .= ' <h2>Usuarios que han hecho la pago efectivo</h2><br>'.$datos[4].'<br>';
    }
 $body .= 'codigo html';
Send_Mail($to,$subject,$body);
}
```

Pero al final igualmente no obtengo nada
Como puedo hacer para enviar todo el resultado obtenido?

Pense en generar un archivo pdf obtener todos los datos y adjuntarlo al correo, pero quiero ver si existe una posibilidad aqui
ATTE: si me trae los datos correctamente si hago un hecho a las condicionales pero sin $body .= , si lo hago con $body .= solo me trae como 2 resultados

Comment: Existe el índice 8 de $datos? Puedes hacer un var_dump($datos) inmediatamente después del while y ver sí es lo que quieres.

Comment: despues del while me lanzara el ultimo dato obtenido y eso es lo que no quiero por eso dentro del while colocaba el envio del correo pero igual no funciono, lo que hice fue generar un pdf y luego enviar el adjunto con el correo

Comment: Quizás estaba mal formado el código HTML y eso hacía que los datos no se vieran en pantalla. Te fijaste el código HTML del mail, a ver si los datos estaban ahí?

Comment: Yo hice esto: dentro del while coloque el body = su html con su codigo pero por alguna razon cuando lo envia sin enviar el email, es decir, en la pantalla como tal solo reflejaban esos ultimos, asi que como tal no entendi mucho porque sucedia estando dentro del while pero bueno..

Comment: ¿Antes de hacer el método Send_Mail, si imprimes $body qué obtienes? ¿Está vacía la variable?

Comment: Si imprimia $body obtenia remetidamente el formato y en el medio solo me arrojaba 1 resultado o algo asi, nisiquiera me traia todos los que pedia